# Python regex match quotes

Tags: python, regex

I try to match words only if the word to compare and the string is in single quote like this :

```
foo foo #match
'foo' foo #don't match
foo 'foo' #don't match
'foo' 'foo' #match
foo 'foo #match
foo foo' #match
```

I tried this regex :

```
((?<!')|((\')?))foo((?!')|(\W*))(?=\W\s*|$)
```

but the output is :

```
foo foo #match it's good
'foo' foo #don't match it's good
foo 'foo' #match it's not good
foo 'foo #match it's good
foo foo' #match it's good
'foo' 'foo' #match it's good
```

Also if i try with a letter all the words with this letter match that I don't want but if I add `\b` all the regex doesn't work ...

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to match if the first and second word is identical and only if both are either (1) surrounded by quotes, (2) not surrounded by quotes, (3) quotations are incomplete? Also what about `'foo foo` and `foo' foo`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and the matches you've proposed (no more no less) the regex below will work.

Note: I've also added double quotes in the regex (on top of single quotes). You can remove them if you don't want to match double quotes `"`

```
(?:^(['"])(\w+)\1\s+\1\2\1$)|(?:^(\w+)\s+\3$)|(?:^(\w+)\s+(?:['"]\4$|\4['"]$))
```

To see this regex in use click [this](https://regex101.com/r/EO0Pr1/1) link

---

This also works and it's slightly shorter.

```
(?:^(['"]{0,1})(\w+)\1\s+(?:(?:(['"]{0,1})\2\1)|(?:\1\2(['"]{0,1})))$)
```

To see this regex in use click [this](https://regex101.com/r/EO0Pr1/2) link

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want but how to add specific word with findall or match or seach ? if they are : 'foo' and 'bar'  and I want only match with 'bar' ? Thanks again.

Comment: I, personally, would do the check outside of regex. Do it in your code. It's the second capture group